# Char array allocation

Tags: c++, character-arrays

In C++, if I do:

```
char myArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

Does that allocate 10 spaces? The last element being '/0'?

What about:

```
char myArray[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

Did I allocate only 9 spaces in this case? Is this bad?

And, finally, what happens when I do:

```
char myArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','/0'};
```

Comment: '/0' is probably not what you meant: it is a multicharacter literal whose value is implementation-defined. Try using '\0' instead.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> char myArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
> ```
>
> Does that allocate 10 spaces? The last element being '/0'?

No. 9.

---

> ```
> char myArray[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
> ```
>
> Did I allocate only 9 spaces in this case?

Yes.

> Is this bad?

No.

---

> and finally what happens when I do
>
> ```
> char myArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','/0'};
> ```

Assuming you meant `'\0'`, exactly what it looks like.

There's no magic in any of these cases — you get precisely what you're asking for.

Automatic null-termination is something that comes into play with *string literals*:

```
char myArray1[10] = "123456789";
char myArray2[9]  = "123456789";  // won't compile - wrong size
char myArray3[]   = "123456789";  // still 10 elements - includes null terminator
```

Comment: No exactly what it looks like, since `'/0'` is a multibyte character literal, which isn't of type `char`, so it will be converted to type `char`. Probably this will overflow and weird stuff, or maybe UB if `char` is signed; I don't know the exact rules.

Comment: @Aardvark: Hah, true. Identified it.

Comment: @Aardvark A multibyte character literal has type `int` with implementation-defined value. If `char` is signed: if the value fits in a `char`, that value is in the array; otherwise, further implementation-defined behaviour. If `char` is unsigned: the value in the array will be the multibyte value modulo 2^n. Not worth playing in this maze of ID behaviour. :D

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll only get the trailing `NUL` when using a string literal, i.e.:

```
// Array of 10 bytes
char myArray[] = "123456789";

// same as:
char myArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','\0'};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char myArray[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

This only allocates 9 elements.

```
char myArray[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

Yes, this line also allocates 9 elements.

```
char myArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','/0'};
```

The last one should be `'\0'` instead of `'/0'`.

What you are thinking about should be

```
char myArray[] = "123456789";
```

which allocates 10 characters (1 for the trailing `'\0'` at the end of the string literal)

Answer (score 1):

`char` arrays don't behave differently than any other arrays when you use list-initialization. Would you expect

```
int x[] = {1,2};
```

to magically append a `0` as the last element and make `x` have 3 elements?

In case you provide fewer elements, then the last ones are value-initialized, so

```
char myArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

would be null-terminated, but

```
char myArray[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

isn't.

Comment: @Gaminic and they're different how? The octal `0` is the same as the char `\0`.

Comment: I didn't downvote (proof: I don't have the points required!). I didn't know those two were the same, so I stand corrected.